# How to find an estimated time for multiple file copying based on file size in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I am working in a program where I am doing a file copying programs of multiple files from different sources and should be copied to a single destination.
Here  I have taken a progress bar in which I have to display the progresses of copying file and also the estimated time for completing the file copy process.
So I wanted how can I find the estimated time.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Can you post the code you have ?

Comment: I have not create any code but I want to create it.

Comment: Unfortunately , no one is going to code for you.

Comment: Google must be something really unknown to new SO users .... https://www.google.de/search?q=estimated+copy+time&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&gws_rd=cr&ei=UnsPV4CpHc_e6QT387P4Cg

Comment: (number of files done) * 100 / (total files). If you want something more precise, you'll need to calculate the number of bytes that were previously done since the beginning, that could give you an estimate for how long the next bytes will take. But this might make the progress bar move on both side.

Comment: `Seconds left = ((Total bytes - Bytes copied) / bytes since last second)`